# Retrieve a particular data of format generic date

Tags: powershell

I have a text file which will contain some content as shown below:

```
SnapshotCreateTime   : 7/30/2015 9:15:24 AM
SnapshotCreateTime   : 7/30/2015 9:18:45 AM
SnapshotCreateTime   : 7/31/2015 7:13:26 AM
SnapshotCreateTime   : 7/30/2015 9:22:46 AM
SnapshotCreateTime   : 7/30/2015 9:26:07 AM
```

What I need to do is that I need to retrieve the date format of each and write it to another text file. I have come up with something as below, but not working as expected:

```
$contents = Get-Content "Path\file.txt"
foreach($cont in $contents) {
  $s = $cont -split ':'
  $name = $s[1]
  $name.Trim() | Add-Content "Path\newfile.txt"
}
```

The result of the above script is like:

```
7/30/2015 9
7/30/2015 9
7/31/2015 7
7/30/2015 9
7/30/2015 9
```

What I really need to have is like:

```
7/30/2015
7/30/2015
7/31/2015
7/30/2015
7/30/2015
```

I know select-string might work here, but I cant really say a specific string format other than d/mm/yyyy. Any thoughts or suggestions to achieve what I mentioned. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple regex where you select the date and replace the string with the capture group:

```
$contents | % { 
    $_ -replace '.*: (.*/.*/....).*', '$1' | 
        Add-Content "Path\newfile.txt" 
}
```

Comment: You mean to replace my current code (entirely)with the above given.?

Answer (score 1):

You split on ':' which is also in hours. You can split on space and take the forth element.

```
$contents = Get-Content "Path\file.txt"
foreach($cont in $contents) {
  $s = $cont -split ' '
  $name = $s[4]
  $name.Trim() | Add-Content "Path\newfile.txt"
}
```

On my own, I prefer @jsaak regex, or use the `[datetime]::ParseExact()` method to get the date.